# Abnormal JSON Parse

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON String as `{1}` or possibly `{2}` and I need to parse it and obtain the integer parsed.

I know I'm doing this incorrectly, but here's what I have thus far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main(){
  jsonStr:="{1}"
  jsonData:=[]byte(jsonStr)
  var v uint
  json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &v)
  data:=v
  fmt.Println(data)
}
```

In this example, the `data` variable should contain the integer value of 1 or 2 if the `jsonStr` value is `{2}`

From my experience with JSON and Go I usually use a struct and pass that into the Unmarshalling function, but i cannot make a struct out of this data response.

**I looked at the API Documentation and found no solution for a string parse without a struct**

Comment: that ain't valid json.

Comment: That's the response Im getting and need to parse. There's no way to parse that as is? Maybe I use something else than JSON Decoding.

Comment: its not json - you could manually parse it...

Comment: Can you assist in how to accomplish that? Or atleast direct me somewhere?

Comment: just remove the `{` and `}` and parse the result.

Comment: Use regex? Can't think of better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
import "regexp"

re:=regexp.MustCompile("[0-9A-Za-z]+")
val:=re.FindAllString(jsonStr,-1)[0]
```

Comment: Yes. Use *[regex101](https://regex101.com)* for testing - awesome website.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives to regexes since they are resource heavy and tend to be slower than other solutions, errors are ignored for brevity. In prod they wouldn't be.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    str := "{1}"
    num, _ := strconv.ParseInt(string(str[1]), 10, 64)
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

or something more robust that doesn't care about the number of digits in the `{}` field.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    str := "{341}"
    num, _ := strconv.ParseInt(string(str[1:len(str)-1]), 10, 64)
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

Small benchmark image showing how much slower regexes are than other solutions. They should be used when other options are available or if performance isn't an issue/concern.
[image]

Even something like this will out perform a regex

```
var n string
for _, r := range str {
    if unicode.IsDigit(r) {
        n += string(r)
    }
}
```

code for benchmark 
https://goplay.space/#PLMtSrMTN9k

Answer (score 0):

As noted by commenters, your example strings [are not valid JSON](http://www.json.org/) since brace-delimited JSON documents must be objects with a list of key-value pairs (e.g. `{"x":1}`, and numbers are plain (e.g. `2`). 
 However, this simple notation of a "brace enclosed integer" could easily be parsed a number of ways, ultimately by checking the syntax of `OPEN_BRACE, DIGIT+, CLOSE_BRACE`.

The example code below checks that the first rune of a given string is an open brace `{`, the last is a close brace `}`, and everything in between can be parsed as an integer using [`strconv.ParseInt(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt):

```
func main() {
  ss := []string{"{1}", "{2}", "{-123}", "{foo}", "{10", "20}", "30"}
  for _, s := range ss {
    x, err := parseBraceNumber(s)
    fmt.Printf("s=%-10qx=%-10derr=%v\n", s, x, err)
  }
  // s="{1}"     x=1         err=<nil>
  // s="{2}"     x=2         err=<nil>
  // s="{-123}"  x=-123      err=<nil>
  // s="{foo}"   x=0         err=invalid brace number "{foo}"
  // s="{10"     x=0         err=invalid brace number "{10"
  // s="20}"     x=0         err=invalid brace number "20}"
  // s="30"      x=0         err=invalid brace number "30"
}

func parseBraceNumber(s string) (int64, error) {
  if len(s) < 3 || s[0] != '{' || s[len(s)-1] != '}' {
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid brace number %q", s)
  }
  x, err := strconv.ParseInt(s[1:len(s)-1], 10, 64)
  if err != nil {
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid brace number %q", s)
  }
  return x, nil
}
```

Of course, other strategies are possible (e.g. using regular expressions) and ultimately it is up to you to decide what implementation is best for your use case.